# О широте значений понятия "терроризм"

Tags: лексика

Могут ли террором быть названы неполитические преступления? Если, например, при ограблении банка люди в масках обращают сотрудников-бухгалтеров в заложников, преследуя только собственные финансовые цели, можно это назвать террором? Какая категория преступников имеет основания называться террористами?

Answer (score 1):

Задача у грабителей — ограбить, у тех же, о ком вопрошаете, — внушить страх и/или повлиять на общественное мнение или на руководство этого самого общества с целью изменения принятых ими решений (действий).

Comment: Можно ли назвать всякую деятельность террористов преступлением?

Comment: @Владимир мытьё посуды, посадка деревьев — всё это подходит под понятие "всякая деятельность", поэтому нет конечно.

Comment: Имеется в виду не всякая деятельность, а "всякая деятельность террористов". К примеру, запугивание населения, подрыв моджахедом общественного здания есть преступление?

Comment: @Владимир именно!

Answer (score 0):

Террорист - тот, кто убивает против целей государства. Если вы убиваете ради гос-ва, то вы уже боец спецподразделения, солдат и т.п.

Например, если одни люди сбили российский самолет - они, конечно, террористы. Но если сотни детей в Сирии погибли под бомбами российских пилотов, они авыполняют приказы Родины и получают награды, верно?

Или, например, преступления Ленина или Сталина против своего народа - явный политический террор. Но в СССР это называлось борьбой с "врагами народа" или с "буржуйским элементом".

Таких примеров можно привести тысячи.

Поэтому значение слова террорист несет сугубо политический смысл в нашем мире. ;)

Comment: А если убийство совершается за пределами территории Родины, это считается терроризмом? К примеру, сбитый русский самолет за пределами России.

Comment: @Serg Z. Большевики в определёный период _открыто_ называли свою политику **красным террором** (см. википедию), и в преподавании истории в СССР это не скрывалось, а сам термин К. Т. принимался. Более того, терроризм досоветских времён (антигосудартсвенной направленности) был "в почёте" в СССР, и именами террористов (Халтурин, Каляев, Перовская, Желябов...) называли улицы. Так что направленность Т. бывает разной, хотя характер всегда политический (серийных маньяков-убийц от террористов всегда отличают).

Answer (score 0):

Террористы, в отличие от серийных убийц-маньяков и грабителей, *всегда* преследуют политические цели. Другое дело, что "технологически" *грабители* могут применять **методы** запугивания и шантажа, *свойственные террористам* (взятие заложников и т. п.). Но при этом они добиваются только того, чтобы им дали шанс скрыться. В Уголовном кодексе статья 213.3 "Терроризм" в своём определении ограничивает это понятие двумя мотивами:

> ... **в целях** (а) нарушения общественной безопасности либо (б) воздействия на
>   принятие решений органами власти...

Формально действия со вторым мотивом (вынудить власти предоставить транспортные средства для побега) при **методах** "создающих опасность гибели людей" **можно** подвести под статью "терроризм", но для грабителей это станет лишь сопутствующим аспектом их преступления.